# char* to char[] - free necessary?

Tags: c, char

assume the following scenario:

```
while(!notTheEnd) {
char str[1024];
char* ptr_to_str;


/* some strcat, strcpy on str */

ptr_to_str = str;

chmod(ptr_to_str, 0777);
}
```

Do I have to set the char* ptr_to_str = NULL and free it to avoid memory leak ?

Just a theoretical question I was thinking of.

Comment: `while(!notTheEnd)` - "while not not the end"? Looks like a bug.

Comment: haha ya you're right. Just a quick imaginary scenario ;) no real code.

Comment: ptr_to_str is just a pointer don't forget, you have to figure out where the actual data comes from and in this case, it is from your local (read: stack) variable 'str'. Since it's allocated on the stack, there is no need to free/delete it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only have to `free()` what you have `malloc()`ed. Therefore: No.

See also the manpage for [free()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free):

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc() or realloc(). Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already been called before, undefined behavior occurs. If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed.

Note that other functions may use `malloc()` or alike internally thus also requiring the returned buffer to be free'd (e.g. [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)).

Setting the pointer to `NULL` is not required at all. It however adds some convenience as subsequent calls to `free()` on this pointer will not expose the application to undefined behavior. And, if done consistently, you can check whether the pointer indeed points to an object or not.

Comment: ok thank you. I thought of something like that, but in some way I was a bit unsure O:-)

Answer (score 4):

You never called `malloc()` so you don't need to call `free()`.

What you have is an pointer to an character array on stack, it does not need explicit deallocation.

Answer (score 3):

No, as long as you don't allocate memory (on heap) you don't need to free it. There are some exceptions (such as [`strdup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html)), but this is the general rule.

Answer (score 1):

`char str[1024]` will allocate 1024 bytes in current stack. And this space will be automatically "popped out" when function returns. So you don't need to explicitly free this memory.